# Working with returned data in Nodejs after web hook verification

Tags: shopify, webhooks

Figured out how to verify request is coming from Shopify with the following:

```
const app = express();

app.use('/webhooks', bodyParser.raw({ type: 'application/json' }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

function isFromShopify(req) {
    const hmac = req.get('X-Shopify-Hmac-Sha256')

    const hash = crypto
     .createHmac('sha256', process.env.SHOPIFY_API_WEBHOOK)
     .update(req.body, 'utf8', 'hex')
     .digest('base64')

   if (hash === hmac) {
      console.log('From Shopify!');
   return true;
   } else {
      console.log('Not from Shopify!')
   return false;
   }
}
```

However, now I need to process data coming back, but when I console log it it's in hex. Is there another way to check if its from Shopify while keeping the response as JSON?

```
app.post('/webhooks/orders/create', async (req, res) => {

  if (isFromShopify(req)) {
    console.log(req.body)
    res.sendStatus(200);
  } else {
    res.sendStatus(403);
  }
})
```

Returns

From Shopify!
<Buffer 7b 22 69 64 22 3a 38 32 30 39 38 32 39 31 31 39 34 36 31 35 34 35 30 38 2c 22 65 6d 61 69 6c 22 3a 22 6a 6f 6e 40 64 6f 65 2e 63 61 22 2c 22 63 6c 6f ... 6501 more bytes>

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `verify` property on `body-parser` to set a property on the request which has the value of the raw request.

Change:

```
app.use('/webhooks', bodyParser.raw({ type: 'application/json' }));
```

to use the `verify` prop like below:

```js
app.use(
  '/webhooks',
  express.json({
    verify: (req, res, buf) => {
      req.raw = buf;
    },
  })
);
```

And now you can access the JSON value and the raw value in your methods.

```js
// raw body value
req.raw;
// JSON value
req.body;
```